# How to provide custom color like #ffa500 to Google Calendar API colorId when inserting an event?

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api

I have integrate google calender with Laravel using `google/apiclient` package.

When I insert an event I want to give the created event my own color like `#ffa500`, There are some color ids like `1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11` which do not match our brand.

Isn't there any way to provide `#ffa500` instead of `6`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible.

There is this answer from a Google support question:

- https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/4053448/how-to-add-customized-color-to-the-palette-in-my-calendar?hl=en&msgid=7357888

You can also create a feature request on Google's Issue tracker on the Calendar component, this is the link to the template:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906

Comment: Thank you Kessy for replying me, offcourse  I will create a feature request.